# Error Handling in Python: Handling Custom Exceptions within a Decorator

Tags: python, exception, decorator

```
class CustomException(Exception):
    pass

def custom_decorator(func):
    def wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
        try:
            result = func(*args, **kwargs)
            return result
        except CustomException as e:
            print(f"CustomException occurred: {str(e)}")
    return wrapper

@custom_decorator
def divide(a, b):
    if b == 0:
        raise CustomException("Cannot divide by zero")
    return a / b

divide(10, 0)
```

Question:

I have a Python code snippet with a custom decorator that handles exceptions. The divide function divides two numbers, but if the second number is zero, it raises a CustomException with an appropriate message. The decorator custom_decorator wraps the function and catches the CustomException.

When I run the code, the exception is raised but not caught by the decorator. How can I modify the code to ensure that the CustomException is properly caught by the decorator and the error message is printed?

I have already tried modifying the decorator, but the exception still propagates to the main program. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I've tested it's working as expected, can you include more details what is not working

Answer (score 0):

This code is perfectly fine. Can you attach the output you are getting? Here the output is as per your expectations:

https://ideone.com/O7I8eC

```
# your code goes here
class CustomException(Exception):
    pass
 
def custom_decorator(func):
    def wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
        try:
            result = func(*args, **kwargs)
            return result
        except CustomException as e:
            print(f"CustomException occurred: {str(e)}")
    return wrapper
 
@custom_decorator
def divide(a, b):
    if b == 0:
        raise CustomException("Cannot divide by zero")
    return a / b
 
divide(10, 0)
```